# BinaryTree Employee Class

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, nodes

First create a class called EmployeeInfo that holds two private data members. One data member is an integer called empID which holds the id number of the employee. The second data member is a string called empName which holds the full name of the employee. The program will create an instance of the binary tree class with a data type of EmployeeInfo (BinaryTree). The binary tree will be sorted by the Employee ID number found in the EmployeeInfo class. The program should then allow the user to search for Employee by the Employee ID. If the employee is found in the tree, its name and ID should be displayed. If not, a message should be displayed indicating that it was not found.

I'm having a problem displaying the employee number and name. I get a long list of error codes that I can't figure out. Please point me in the right direction. Above is what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This class is a template class that creates a binary
// tree that can hold values of any data type. It has 
// functions to insert a node, delete a node, display the
// tree In Order, Pre Order and Post Order, search for a 
// value, count the number of total nodes, left nodes, 
// and a function to determine the height of the tree.

template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        T value;            // The value in the node
        TreeNode *left;     // Pointer to left child node
        TreeNode *right;    // Pointer to right child node
    };

    TreeNode *root;         // Pointer to the root node

    // Private member functions
    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    void destroySubTree(TreeNode *);
    void deleteNode(T, TreeNode *&);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
    void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPreOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPostOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    int counter(TreeNode *);
    int leafCounter(TreeNode *);
    int height(TreeNode *);

public:
    // Constructor
    BinaryTree()
    { root = NULL; }

    // Destructor
    ~BinaryTree()
    { destroySubTree(root); }

    // Binary tree operations
    void insertNode(T);
    bool searchNode(T);
    void remove(T);

    void displayPreOrder() const
    { displayPreOrder(root); }

    void displayInOrder() const
    { displayInOrder(root); }

    void displayPostOrder() const
    { displayPostOrder(root); }

    // Node counter
    int counter()
    { 
        int n = counter(root);
        return n;
    }

    // Leaf counter
    int leafCounter()
    {
        int leaf = leafCounter(root);
        return leaf;
    }

    // Height of the tree
    int height()
    {
        int h = height(root);
        return h;
    }
};

//*********************************************************
// insert function accepts a TreeNode pointer and a       *
// pointer to a node. The function inserts the node into  *
// the tree pointer to by the TreeNode pointer. This      *
// function is call recursively.                          *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        nodePtr = newNode;              // Insert the node
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode); // Search the left branch
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);// Search the right branch
}

//*********************************************************
// insertNode creates anew node to hold num as its value  *
// and passes it to the insert function.                  *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
 void BinaryTree<T>::insertNode(T item)
 {
     TreeNode *newNode;     // Pointer to a new node

     // Create anew node and store num in it
     newNode = new TreeNode;
     newNode->value = item;
     newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;

     // Insert the node
     insert(root, newNode);
 }

//**********************************************************
// destroySubTree is called by the destructor. It deletes  *
// all nodes in the tree.                                  *
//**********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::destroySubTree(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
     if (nodePtr)
     {
         if (nodePtr->left)
             destroySubTree(nodePtr->left);
         if (nodePtr->right)
             destroySubTree(nodePtr->right);
         delete nodePtr;
     }
}

//**********************************************************
// searchNode determines if a value is present in the tree.*
// If so, the function returns true. Otherwise it returns  *
// false.
//**********************************************************
template <class T>
bool BinaryTree<T>::searchNode(T item)
{
    TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->value == item)
            return true;
        else if (item < nodePtr->value)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
        else
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
    }
    return false;
}

//*********************************************************
// remove calls deleteNode to delete the node whode value *
// member is the same as num                              *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::remove(T item)
{
    deleteNode(item, root);
}

//*********************************************************
// deleteNode deletes the node whose value member is the  *
// same as num                                            *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::deleteNode(T item, TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    if (item < nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->left);
    else if (item > nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(item, nodePtr->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(nodePtr);
}

//*********************************************************
// makeDeletion takes a reference to apointer to the node *
// that is to be deleted. The node is removed and the     *
// branches of the tree below the node are reattached     *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::makeDeletion(TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    // Define a temporary pointer to use in reattaching
    // the left subtree
    TreeNode *tempNodePtr;

    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot delete empty node.\n";
    else if (nodePtr->right == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;    // Reattach the left child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->left == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;   // Reattach the right child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    } 

}
//*********************************************************
// The displayInOrder function displays the values in the *
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via inorder traversal   *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayInOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->value.getEmpID() << " "
                     << getEmpName() << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}
//*********************************************************
// The displayPreOrder function displays the values in the*
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via Preorder traversal  *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPreOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}
//*********************************************************
// displayPostOrder function displays the values in the   *
// subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via Postorder traversal *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::displayPostOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
    }
}

//*********************************************************
// counter counts the number of nodes the tree has        *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::counter(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return counter(nodePtr->left) +1+ counter(nodePtr->right);
}

//*********************************************************
// leafCounter counts the number of leaf nodes in the tree*
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::leafCounter(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        return 0;
    else if (nodePtr->left == NULL && nodePtr->right == NULL)
        return 1;
    else 
        return leafCounter(nodePtr->left) + leafCounter(nodePtr->right);
}

//*********************************************************
// height returns the height of the tree                  *
//*********************************************************
template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::height(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{

    if(nodePtr == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (height(nodePtr->left) <= height(nodePtr->right))
        return (height(nodePtr->right) +1);
    else
        return (height(nodePtr->left) +1);

}
#endif
```

My EMPLOYEE CLASS

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#define EMPLOYEEINFO_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// This class has two data members to hold the employee ID
// and the name of the employee.

class EmployeeInfo
{
private:
    int empID;      // To hold employee ID number
    string empName; // To hold employee name

public:
    // Default Constructor
    EmployeeInfo();

    // Constructor
    EmployeeInfo(int, string);

    // Mutators
    void setEmpID(int);
    void setEmpName(string);

    // Accessors
    int getEmpID();
    string getEmpName();

    bool operator < (const EmployeeInfo &e)
        {
        if (empID < e.empID)
            return true;
        if (empName < e.empName)
            return true;
        return false;
        }
};
#endif
```

**EDIT** I overloaded the `<` operator and all the errors went away

```
#include "EmployeeInfo.h"

//*********************************************************
// Default constructor intializes the data members        *
//*********************************************************
EmployeeInfo::EmployeeInfo()
{
    empID = 0;
    empName = "";
}

//*********************************************************
// Constructor sets the data members                      *
//*********************************************************
EmployeeInfo::EmployeeInfo(int ID, string name)
{
    empID = ID;
    empName = name;
}

//*********************************************************
// setEmpID stores the employee ID number                 *
//*********************************************************
void EmployeeInfo::setEmpID(int ID)
{
    empID = ID;
}

//*********************************************************
// setEmpName stores the full name of the employee        *
//*********************************************************
void EmployeeInfo::setEmpName(string name)
{
    empName = name;
}

//*********************************************************
// getEmpID returns the employee ID number                *
//*********************************************************
int EmployeeInfo::getEmpID()
{
    return empID;
}

//*********************************************************
// getEmpName returns the full name of the employee       *
//*********************************************************
string EmployeeInfo::getEmpName()
{
    return empName;
}
```

MAIN

```
#include "EmployeeInfo.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Create an instance of BinaryTree
    BinaryTree<EmployeeInfo> tree;

    // Create an EmployeeInfo object
    EmployeeInfo info;
    EmployeeInfo emp1(1021, "John Williams");
    EmployeeInfo emp2(1057, "Bill Witherspoon");

    // Store the information
    info.setEmpID(1021);
    info.setEmpID(1057);

    info.setEmpName("John Williams");
    info.setEmpName("Bill Witherspoon");

    tree.insertNode(emp1);
    tree.insertNode(emp2);

    // Display in order
    tree.displayInOrder();
}
```

Comment: So I overloaded the `<` operator and it seems to work. I will finish the project to see what else I run in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide overloads of the `<` and `>` operators for your `EmployeeInfo` class, and maybe other operators as well. At present it doesn't know how to evaluate `item < nodePtr->value` etc.

I don't see anything in the assignment that requires `EmployeeInfo` to have a default constructor.

You don't really need your `destroySubtree()` method. Your destructor should just read:

```
delete root;
```

and `TreeNode` should have a destructor that reads:

```
delete left;
delete right;
```

You don't need to check these for zero either, `delete` already does that.

Comment: Ok I will work on the overloaded operators and work on your other suggestions